# Opening a port and testing

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, http, localhost

I would like if it's possible to communicate with a port and send to it some information.

But , when trying to open:

```
http://localhost:8080
```

even with a browser : it gives me :

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to localhost:8080
```

Can you help me with this?

Comment: What is listening on port 8080?

Comment: You need to have a process listening to port 8080. Have you done that?

Comment: @bitfiddler I am not getting your point.

Comment: The browser is attempting to read from port 8080 but there is no process listening to that port. You need to understand how to activate a process on that port so the browser has something to talk to.

Comment: @bitfiddler If you could write your answer below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser is attempting to read from port 8080 but there is no process listening to that port. You need to understand how to activate a process on that port so the browser has something to talk to. If you are using Visual Studio, try using their example of a simple console app to listen on that port. Take a look at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener.aspx Have fun...

Comment: sorry I did nt find the way to activate a process on that port, using C++.

Comment: Try this MSDN How To http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecc85927(v=vs.100).aspx [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecc85927(v=vs.100).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

According to the answer of Bitfiddler:

The browser is attempting to read from port 8080 but there is no process listening to that port. You need to understand how to activate a process on that port so the browser has something to talk to